# how to set gameobject velocity relative to screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen

I was wondering how do I set gameobject velocity relative to screen in C#? for example if the gameobject is falling down on the screen it will still be falling down on the screen even the world have moved.
[image]

Comment: Not easily. I can't even figure out where I'd start to approach this. Keep in mind that if your camera is moving also (which it would have to be for the world origin to do that, as well as rotating), the block would not have the described motion unless its motion is complex. And adding two complex motions together to get a simple 2D vector result is not easy. (Same goes for the reverse process, unless the object is a child of the camera, which is not always the best idea)

Comment: If you can use position instead of velocity you might be able to utilize WorldToScreenPoint

Comment: sounds like a mobile game, go nuts and try the gyroscope :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 (the easy way)**

You can set the object to be a child of the camera - this way camera movement will impact the movement of the object so you should achieve the effect you want.

**Solution 2**

```
const float Velocity = 1.0f;
const float DistanceFromCamera = 1.0f;

Vector3 ScreenCoords = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  

void Update()
{        
    ScreenCoords.x += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 worldCoords = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(ScreenCoords);
    worldCoords.z = DistanceFromCamera;

    target.position = worldCoords;
}
```

This does the following:

- keep the object position relative to the camera in variable ScreenCoords
- update the ScreenCoords (you can update if by specified velocity or try to utilize the physics engine through fields like [Rigidbody2D.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) or [Rigidbody.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)
- transform screen coords to world coords and update object position